# Converting json to csv keeping non-ascii characters intact

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have a .json file which is in this form

```
{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "“cool jeans,” i tell a cute boy\nlittle did he know that im talking about his genes bc those chromosomes have combined beautifully ay papi", "is_quote_status": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "id": 786650297116532736, "favorite_count": 631, "source": "<a href=\"http://bufferapp.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Buffer</a>", "retweeted": false, "coordinates": null, "entities": {"symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "hashtags": [], "urls": []}, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "retweet_count": 233, "id_str": "786650297116532736", "favorited": false, "user": {"follow_request_sent": false, "has_extended_profile": false, "profile_use_background_image": true, "default_profile_image": false, "id": 321445166, "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000024702436/c56435230dd53432a3aa7685fdd98cf7.jpeg", "verified": false, "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782124224198631424/zuUAjl5o_normal.jpg", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF", "entities": {"url": {"urls": [{"indices": [0, 23], "expanded_url": "https://youtu.be/1qjR-p_o3BE", "display_url": "youtu.be/1qjR-p_o3BE"}]}, "description": {"urls": []}}, "followers_count": 4992012, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", "id_str": "321445166", "profile_background_color": "182D66", "listed_count": 5284, "is_translation_enabled": false, "utc_offset": 7200, "statuses_count": 28488, "description": "There's a fine line between being sassy and being an asshole and I cross it everyday. Youtuber and student. Link in bio thatssarcasmposts@gmail.com", "friends_count": 55420, "location": "Cape Town", "profile_link_color": "536BA7", "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782124224198631424/zuUAjl5o_normal.jpg", "following": false, "geo_enabled": false, "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/321445166/1475082140", "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000024702436/c56435230dd53432a3aa7685fdd98cf7.jpeg", "screen_name": "ThatsSarcasm", "lang": "en", "profile_background_tile": false, "favourites_count": 3931, "name": "joke", "notifications": false, "created_at": "Tue Jun 21 15:52:41 +0000 2011", "contributors_enabled": false, "time_zone": "Pretoria", "protected": false, "default_profile": false, "is_translator": false}, "geo": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "lang": "en", "created_at": "Thu Oct 13 19:30:20 +0000 2016", "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "place": null}
{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "If you're not following @relatabIe for the most relatable tweets ever, then what are you doing?I love their posts", "is_quote_status": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "id": 786649227002781696, "favorite_count": 29, "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "retweeted": false, "coordinates": null, "entities": {"symbols": [], "user_mentions": [{"id": 485854360, "indices": [24, 34], "id_str": "485854360", "screen_name": "relatabIe", "name": "Relatable Tweets!"}], "hashtags": [], "urls": []}, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "retweet_count": 6, "id_str": "786649227002781696", "favorited": false, "user": {"follow_request_sent": false, "has_extended_profile": false, "profile_use_background_image": true, "default_profile_image": false, "id": 321445166, "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000024702436/c56435230dd53432a3aa7685fdd98cf7.jpeg", "verified": false, "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782124224198631424/zuUAjl5o_normal.jpg", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF", "entities": {"url": {"urls": [{"indices": [0, 23], "expanded_url": "https://youtu.be/1qjR-p_o3BE", "display_url": "youtu.be/1qjR-p_o3BE"}]}, "description": {"urls": []}}, "followers_count": 4992012, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", "id_str": "321445166", "profile_background_color": "182D66", "listed_count": 5284, "is_translation_enabled": false, "utc_offset": 7200, "statuses_count": 28488, "description": "There's a fine line between being sassy and being an asshole and I cross it everyday. Youtuber and student. Link in bio thatssarcasmposts@gmail.com", "friends_count": 55420, "location": "Cape Town", "profile_link_color": "536BA7", "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782124224198631424/zuUAjl5o_normal.jpg", "following": false, "geo_enabled": false, "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/321445166/1475082140", "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000024702436/c56435230dd53432a3aa7685fdd98cf7.jpeg", "screen_name": "ThatsSarcasm", "lang": "en", "profile_background_tile": false, "favourites_count": 3931, "name": "joke", "notifications": false, "created_at": "Tue Jun 21 15:52:41 +0000 2011", "contributors_enabled": false, "time_zone": "Pretoria", "protected": false, "default_profile": false, "is_translator": false}, "geo": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "lang": "en", "created_at": "Thu Oct 13 19:26:05 +0000 2016", "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "place": null}
```

The python code I used to convert was

```
import json
import csv

x=open('MyFile.json')
data=json.load(x)
x.close()

f=csv.writer(open('data.csv','wb+')) 
for item in data:
    f.writerow(item["text"])

f.close()
```

My aim was to write only the text attribute(3rd one) in the csv file but it shows following error

```
File "to_csv.py", line 10, in <module>
  f.writerow(item["text"])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f60f' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have searched and found a hint. I replaced line 10 as:

```
f.writerow(unicode(item["text"]).encode("utf-8"))
```

but to no avail. Can't find a way to keep non-ascii characters intact.

EDIT: thanks to mx0's solution, the code runs fine. one thing i noticed was that there is newline character because of which a single text attribute gets printed in two lines, for example check the text attribute in the first line of json file. there is a newline character between 'boy' and 'little'. i wanted to avoid printing those so i wrote this code

```
f = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb+'))
for item in data:
    if item["text"].encode('utf-8')=='\n':
        f.writerow(" ")
    else:
        f.writerow([item["text"].encode('utf-8')])
```

but it doesn't seem to work. anything wrong?

Comment: You want to remove newline or write it to file as `\n`?

Comment: remove newlines in a single text attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Question didn't specify python version, first answer was for python 3.

There are few problems in your code.

Your json file is not valid (or you pasted it wrong here). Should be like

```
[{"first":"object"}, {"second":"object"}]
```

When reading json, you have to specify encoding

```
x = open('MyFile.json', encoding='utf-8')
```

When writing, don't use binary mode, and specify encoding. Also add `newline=''` parameter or else file will have double newlines in output.

```
f = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline=''))
```

Function `writerow` takes a list and writes it as row. Your text will end up as `I,f, ,y,o,u,',r,e, ,n,o,t` if you don't enclose it in another list

```
f.writerow([item["text"]])
```

Complete working example

**Python 3.5**

```
import json
import csv

x = open('MyFile.json', encoding='utf-8')
data = json.load(x)
x.close()

f = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline=''))
for item in data:
    f.writerow([item["text"]])
```

**Python 2.7**

For python 2 you were very close to get working program. In py2 `csv.writerow` writes files in `bytes` mode, but your `item["text"]` is unicode string so you have to encode it before. This will work as long your json file is really unicode encoded.

```
import json
import csv

x = open('MyFile.json')
data = json.load(x)
x.close()


f = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb+'))
for item in data:
    f.writerow([item["text"].encode('utf-8')])
```

To change newline to space

```
f.writerow([item["text"].replace('\n', ' ').encode('utf-8')])
```

To write newline as `\n`

```
f.writerow([item["text"].replace('\n', '\\n').encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: you are right about writerow, i did get an output in that format. i tried your solution but it says `'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. i removed it and executed the code again but then a new error popped up saying `file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
`. i m using python 2.7 if it affects somehow. sorry didn't mention that before

Comment: i also executed the code twice, removing encoding parameter and keeping newline parameter in the csv.writer() the first time and removing newline parameter and keeping encoding paramter the second time. both times it said that the paramter 'newline'/'encoding' is invalid keyword argument for this function.

Comment: @shad0w `python 2.7` it actually makes big difference. Check updated code.

Comment: i have another doubt that i have edited in my question above. please help me out with it

Comment: thanks again. it worked like a charm. sorry for replying so late. i have another question. in the text attribute, there are certain characters like left double quotation mark, right double quotation mark. what if i want to save them as unicode characters. for example in this way: \u201cgoing to cut the grass\u201d